# The \b in my code won't bring the cursor back

Tags: c, cursor, backspace

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int answer;
    printf("Please insert your desired budget :"); //normal printf functions.
    printf(" $_____\b\b\b\b"); //This should move the curser back 4 spaces.
    //The program outputs the line followed with 4 inverted question marks.
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    printf("So your budget is %d", answer);
    return 0;
}
```

How come the output is 4 inverted question marks? I am using xcode on mac, could that the problem?

Comment: A few things: 1) I would imagine using a floating type for money. 2) you have 5 underscores in the second `printf`. 3) you should do some error checking on the input. 3) You probably want a `\n` on that last print. Otherwise, this looks like it should work.

Comment: Which version of gcc you are using on Mac? It is running fine on Ubuntu. 
`printf(" $____\b\b\b\b");` Mistakenly, you have inserted 5 underscores instead of four, anyhow it is working fine on mine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to run it in a terminal environment that supports `\b` escape sequences. The console in Xcode must not understand them.

If you run it in the Terminal app, it should be fine.

Comment: +1. And for the "gory details" on terminals : http://linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the book [C Primer Plus] 6th Page.91

list3.10 escape.c

```
/* escape.c -- uses escape characters */
#include <stdio.h>


 int main(void)
{
     float salary;
     printf("\aEnter your desired monthly salary:");/* 1 */ 
     printf(" $_______\b\b\b\b\b\b\b"); /* 2 */ 
     scanf("%f", &salary);
     printf("\n\t$%.2f a month is $%.2f a year.", salary,salary * 12.0); /* 3 */        
     return 0; 
}
```

The author says :

> The actual behavior could be different. For instance, XCode 4.6 displays the \a, \b, and \r characters as upside down question marks!

They shows Xcode didn't support the `\b` 
and the Apple [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3992023?tstart=0)also shows the situation.

In my Xcode 5.0,it has the same situation.
[image]